# Bootstrap table filter control how to clear the input box after search use

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The `.clear()` function is not working for my code.  I don't know how to manipulate the tags in jQuery.

event:

```
         
function (){        
    var $table = $('#table')
    if($(".filter-control").is(":visible")){
         $(".filter-control").hide()
        $table.bootstrapTable('refresh')
        $(".filter-control").clear();
    } else {
        $(".filter-control").show()
        $table.bootstrapTable('refresh')
        $(".filter-control").clear();
    }       
}
```

The interesting Html code is

```
  <table>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id"   data-filter-control="input"  data-width ="400"  >Id</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input"   data-width ="400"  >Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price"data-filter-control="input"  data-width ="400"  >Item Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <script>
    function buttons(){
      return {
        btnUsersAdd: {
          text: 'Enable/Disable Filters',
          
          icon:'fa-filter',
          event: function (){
            
            if($(".filter-control").is(":visible")){
                $(".filter-control").hide()
                $(".filter-control").clear(); 
                $table.bootstrapTable('refresh')
            } else {
        $(".filter-control").show()
        $(".filter-control").clear();
        $table.bootstrapTable('refresh')            
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   
  </script>
```

Comment: You *probably* want `$(".filter-control").val("")`

Comment: Can you please elaborate i  have used  $(".filter-control").val(" ")

Comment: Check your console, you should be getting error `$(...).clear is not a function` so change `.clear()` to `.val("")` - but without the html showing exactly what `.filter-control` is, it's only a guess.

Comment: Ohk i will do that and i am pasting the entire html code here

Comment: I have posted the entire html can you check please

Comment: Please format your question correctly.   You can highlight code elements in other text using a backtick ` `like this` - blocks of code should start and end with three backticks.  I've fixed your code 3 times now, but you keep putting it back to unreadable.

Comment: I apologize for that I am new here I was not aware you were doing that. and follow the code after were i wrote i wrote the html code here

Comment: I formatted the code now as well and it's getting unclear for me if this is working in any ways ... still ... you call `clear()` instead of `val("")` as freedomn-m suggested ...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own query,
1.Add the attribute  data-show-filter-control-switch="true" to table
2. make sure there is no data-height attribute as the height of the table changes and it will prevent that.